# Force Varnish to Use Proxy Protocol 1

Tags: nginx, varnish, haproxy

I have HaProxy terminating SSL and passing the requests back to Varnish which then either serves the cached page or requests from Nginx. However, Varnish seems to be treating the request from HaProxy as HTTP/1 not HTTP/2 and failing to serve.

I can see in the Nginx logs the following when I try to hit a page:

```
" while reading PROXY protocol, client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1:8181
2016/08/11 06:53:31 [error] 5682#0: *1 broken header: "GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
User-Agent: curl/7.50.2-DEV
Accept: */*
X-Forwarded-For: IP_Removed
Accept-Encoding: gzip
X-Varnish: 32777
```

I've found something that relates to this [here](https://blog.mythic-beasts.com/2016/05/09/proxy-protocol-nginx-broken-header/) which states that the reason for this is that Nginx does not work with v2 PROXY only v1. So, as a result of this I've forced the use of protocol 1 in HaProxy using the send-proxy rather than send-proxy-v2 switch. But when it gets to Varnish I think that Varnish is converting this in some way to protocol 2 which is causing it to then fail to communicate properly with Nginx.

I have removed Varnish from the equation and connected HaProxy direct to Nginx and it works perfectly via HTTP/2. The problem is something is happening in the Varnish stack and the likely suspect is the proxy protocol v2 being used by Varnish.

So, to cut a long story short, how do I force Varnish to adhere to PROXY1 rather than PROXY2 protocol? I've tried adding PROXY1 into the launch daemon options but Varnish won't accept that. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

UPDATE - I tested HaProxy > Nginx with the send-proxy-v2 switch on the HaProxy backend and it causes the identical problem to when Varnish is introduced into the stack. Switching back to send-proxy on HaProxy fixes the issue. So, I'm convinced that the issue is Varnish using protocol 2 rather than protocol 1. But how to tell it not to?

Comment: Are you sure you are talking about HTTP/2? This has nothing to do with PROXY v2 protocol. Varnish doesn't speak HTTP/2, it's going to be in Varnish 5.x introduced.

Comment: Maybe I'm confusing myself but my understanding of it is that HaProxy operates as TCP not HTTP when dealing with HTTP/2 so it is necessary to use send-proxy with the backend. Nginx is set to receive this with its proxy_protocol switch. I understand that Varnish isn't HTTP/2 or does SSL but it should be passing the protocol back as is to Nginx no?

Answer (score 2):

> I understand that Varnish isn't HTTP/2 or does SSL but it should be passing the protocol back as is to Nginx no?

No.

But first, let's clarify.  HTTP/2 and Proxy protocol V2 have absolutely nothing to do with each other.  Remove HTTP/2 from your mind, as it is not applicable here in any sense.

Your question is, in fact, this:

> If HAProxy is sending Proxy Protocol V1 to Varnish, and Nginx is configured behind Varnish to expect Proxy Protocol V1, why does Nginx complain of broken headers?  Does Varnish not forward Proxy Protocol V1 to the backend?  Does it for some reason send Proxy Protocol V2, instead?

And the answer to that question is that Varnish isn't sending either one.  Neither V1 nor V2.

The only thing you need the Proxy protocol for is so that an HTTP-aware component can receive the client IP address (and port) from a upstream, non-HTTP-aware component, such as HAProxy using `mode tcp` or Amazon ELB with a listener in TCP mode, either of which is typically doing SSL offloading for you and not HTTP request routing, so it needs an alternative mechanism of passing the client address.

The first HTTP-aware component can take that address and set it in an HTTP header, customarily `X-Forwarded-For`, for the benefit of the remaining components in the stack.  As such, there's no reason for Varnish to forward the Proxy protocol onward.  It isn't doing that in your example, and there is no obvious reason why Varnish would even be capable of forwarding the Proxy protocol.¹

And this brings us to the error.  You are misdiagnosing the problem that Nginx is reporting.  The broken header error means that Nginx is receiving something other than Proxy protocol V1.  With Varnish in the loop, there is no Proxy protocol header² present at all in the request to Nginx -- and when a listener is configured to expect the Proxy protocol header, that header is **mandatory**.

If a component is configured to expect Proxy protocol V1 and it is not present, that is **always** an error.  But "not present" means exactly that.  A V1 header is not present.  That does not mean V2 is.  It isn't.

> So, I'm convinced that the issue is Varnish using protocol 2 rather than protocol 1.

You have convinced yourself incorrectly.  Proxy V2 into Nginx -- as you have tried with HAProxy -- is an error, and no Proxy protocol header at all -- as you are seeing from Varnish -- is an error, as explained above.  Both are misconfigurations, though of a different type.  What you have done here is duplicated the error but for an entirely different reason.

If you are sending all requests through Varnish, then configure Varnish to set `X-Forwarded-For` in the forwarded request using the information it learns from the incoming Proxy protocol mesaage.  Remove Proxy protocol from the Nginx configuration.

Or configure HAProxy to operate in HTTP mode and let it insert the header using `option forwardfor`.

---

¹ Clearly, from the error, Varnish is just sending ordinary HTTP headers -- nothing that looks like Proxy protocol.  I don't think it even supports the option of sending Proxy protocol to the origin server, but somebody say something if I've overlooked that capability.

²  I would assert that the Proxy protocol "header" is not properly called a header, given what that implies.  It is a preamble, not a header, though it was unfortunately called a "header" in the standard.  It's most certainly not an *HTTP* header.

Answer (score 0):

If you upgrade Varnish to 5.0 it can send PROXY Protocol version 1 to NGINX by setting ".proxy_header = 1"